# Overlay image with transparent colour and blur

Tags: css, image, colors, overlay

I have a header background image which is loaded into the html by wordpress how do I Overlay it with an RGBA / Transparent colour and blur its contents via CSS?

Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/g0qhxjr9/

In this case where you see the ing url is the wordpress featured image function

```css
#header_img_over {
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: rgba(28,28,34,0.9); 
  filter: blur(20px);
 z-index: 2;
}
.header_bg {
 z-index: -10;
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 245px;
 min-height: 245px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

.header_bg img{
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_img_over"><div class="header_bg"><img src="http://stylrs.com/v05/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/ML_Guildhall_TBL_0009-767x415.jpg"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already got the overlay just change the position in header_bg to relative. and for the blur as @karaokyo said blur filter will do fine take a look at this code it's yours with the filter and overlay [YOUR CODE FIXED](http://codepen.io/zeidanbm/pen/zxRmNV)

This will work in most browsers but not IE and some minor others. For that you can set a fallback to use `progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur` which will only work for IE prior to 10 for IE 10 and up you need to set a fall back to use js. 
I would say if you need to achieve a wide support just use a javascript blur function there are some jquery plugins which are easy to use. if you need more help on that let me know.
I almost forgot there`s feGausianBlur which will work for IE10+ but you need to use svg. so inorder to do this with svg you just create two div to control responsivnes svgmenu1-container and svgmenu1-content then put the svg inside and define the viewBox then inside the defs define the filter where fecomposite will take a couple of attribute your can check what each does on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feComposite)
Then just pass you image with the filter

```
<div class="svgmenu1-container">
<div class="svgmenu1-content">
<svg id="svgimage" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800 500">
<defs>
<filter id="blurthis">
<feComposite operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="0" k4="0" in="SourceGraphic" in2="SourceGraphic" result="inputTo_1"></feComposite>
<feGaussianBlur id="filter_1" stdDeviation="4" data-filterId="1">  </feGaussianBlur></filter></defs>
<image class="svgimage" x="0" y="0" width="800" height="500" xlink:href="/images/yourimage.jpg" alt="myimage" filter="url(#blurthis)"> </image>
</svg>
</div></div>
```

Comment: I was wondering if there is another way of applying the blur other than adding a class to the image? since the img tag is loaded by a wordpress function for me?

Comment: just add the `-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
          filter: blur(5px);` to the header_bg class

Answer (score 1):

Use a blur filter:

```
.header_bg {
    filter: blur(20px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
}
```

Webkit uses -webkit-filter, filter should work for every other modern browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add webkit tag on `#header_img_over` because it's helps run on modern browser.

```
-webkit-filter: blur(20px);
-moz-filter: blur(20px);
-o-filter: blur(20px);
-ms-filter: blur(20px);
filter: blur(20px);
```

**edit**

And if you want to both blur and color overlay, please see my [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1vxhv0s0/2/)

Comment: Hi thanks for the webkit tag that helped but any ideas on how to overlay the image with a semi-transparent colour?

Comment: Thanks but is it possible to do a blur and colour overlay at the same time?

Comment: Yes you can. Here is [link](https://jsfiddle.net/1vxhv0s0/2/). Is it right you want to give a blur effect to an image? (If you want to give a blur to `header_img_over`, you can just add `filter` elements on `header_img_over`)